# Setting a working directory from another drive in R

Tags: r

I have a file which is saved on a different drive than RStudio and I'm trying to set it as the working directory.

```
setwd(dir)
```

Where dir is the copy and pasted file path(windows) string.
I get the error

```
 Error in setwd("dir") : 
  cannot change working directory
```

Since dir has been copied as a path, I cannot work out what the error might be.

Edit: I should have mentioned I have changed the all the \ to / in the file path.

Solved: quotation marks needed around file path.

Comment: It is not a good practice to change the working directory. Can't you call the file directly with a path? like `file.path(dir, name_of_your_file)`

Comment: Windows uses `\ ` as filepath separators. They will need to be escaped to `\\ ` or converted to `/` for R. So if your path looks like `"G:\Folder\subfolder"`, you need to change it to `"G:\\Folder\\subfolder"` or `"G:/Folder/subfolder"`

Comment: Maybe the drive is restricted? Try running RStudio as an administrator and see if it works. But first of all, make sure you don't have any typos in your filepath.

Comment: It's also a good idea to create R projects with unique project folders.  So I have an R Projects folder in my Windows Documents folder and save individual projects to that.  Moreover, you can create a .Rprofile file for each project that loads the project packages when the project is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You should paste the windows path and change backslashes to forward slashes. Did you do this?

```
setwd("Z:/path")
```

Comment: Yes, I did this, but to no avail.